# What is lldb's equivalent one of gdb's start command?

Tags: gdb, lldb

I heavily used `gdb` before, and now give `lldb` a shot. I like `gdb`'s [start](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html) command very much, but I can't find the equivalent one from `lldb`'s [manual](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html). Now I can only use "`b main`" followed by `run` compound instead. So just curious whether there is an equivalent one in `lldb`? Or I can only use the compound of "`b main`" and `run` commands as a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, lldb doesn't have a dedicated `start` command.  The stated motivation for that command is that gdb supports lots of runtimes that don't use a "main" symbol. That makes determining where user code begins non-trivial, and it's useful to have a command that figures that out for you.  We haven't had a need for that in lldb yet.

If you always use `start` to run programs in gdb, then you can just set a breakpoint on main in your `~/.lldbinit` file.  That will get copied to any new targets that get made in your lldb session, and `run` will behave exactly like `start` (for runtimes that use a main symbol).

If it's something you would use a lot but not always, you could make your own version fairly easily using the python extension point in the command interpreter:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#create-a-new-lldb-command-using-a-python-function

Also, feel free to file an Enhancement Request with http://bugs.llvm.org.